# How can I make MVC4 present a page to the user that will not be cached by the browser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using an MVC4 anti-forgery token created with @Html.AntiForgeryToken(). I have a problem as follows:

1. The application opens and a login form is generated for the first time with an antiforgery token for user name of "".
2. The login form is cached in the browser
3. The user goes to another page
4. User clicks the back button and goes back to the login page.
5. Login page is displayed from cache and still has a token for user name of "".

Is there a way in MVC that I can make it so when a user clicks the back button and goes to the login page he is not presented with a cached version.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011780/prevent-caching-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The other question relates to Ajax caching with jQuery.

Comment: @Melina It applies to you too.

Comment: I think u should not use OutputCache for authentication user this is not best practice

Comment: This is a duplicate : )  see my answer (and others) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160105/asp-net-mvc-disable-browser-cache/5546328#5546328

Comment: says who? the last thing you want is a cached login form, and output cache does affect client side. There are other cache alternatives though depending on your scenario (child actions needed or not, etc) see the link I posted above)

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: this is the cache mechanism occurs on server side. He want to disable browser's cache

Comment: My answer was based on tests using a similar design. Using "OutputCache" the action is requested again to return to the page.

Comment: @namkha87 the output cache attribute also sends a client side cache header, it is not only server side. - see my details at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160105/asp-net-mvc-disable-browser-cache/5546328#5546328

Comment: @Adam Tuliper: you saved me from a misunderstanding. Thanks a lot!