# ui-bootstrap-tpls failed to load template

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've inherited an angular project, and it's having problems loading the ui-bootstrap-tpls modules.

For each directive it's trying to use from bootstrap, I get something similar to the following:

Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: template/datepicker/popup.html

I've read about the need to include the tpls version of the ui-bootstrap lib.  (ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js (instead of ui-bootstrap.js)), but having done that as well as every permutation of module injected into my module as a dependency (ui.bootstrap, ui.bootstrap.tpls, template/datepicker/datepicker.html'), but I can't beat it.

Here're my includes:

```
<html class="no-js" ng-app="hiringApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <meta name="layout" content="IRLayout">

    <!-- styles IRLayout-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0-beta.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <!-- BootStrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- font-awesome -->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/content/css/layout.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/content/css/normalize.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/content/css/main.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/Upload.css")">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/content/css/styles.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/content/css/site-specific.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/content/css/rating.css")">

    <!-- Upload -->
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Upload.css")">*@

    <!-- Header Scripts-->
    <!-- Jquery & Jquery UI -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Vendor/underscore-min.js")"></script>

    <!-- BootStrap -->
    <!-- Validate -->
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Analytics -->
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0-beta.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.2/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphael/0.5.1/g.raphael-min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular -->
          <!--  
          <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
          <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
          <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
          <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
            -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/controllers.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/directives.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/filters.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/services.js")"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module("hiringApp").constant("$userProvider", @Model.User.SystemRoles);
        angular.module("hiringApp").constant("$jobProvider", '');
    </script>

    <!-- Upload -->
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/content/js/plupload.full.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/content/js/UploadImage.js")"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js'></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/audio/irAudioRecorder.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("script", required: false)
</head>
```

Here's my app module:

```
var hiringApp = angular.module('hiringApp', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'ngResource', 'filters', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.tpls']);
```

Here's the error:

```
GET http://localhost:54720/template/tooltip/tooltip-popup.html 404 (Not Found) angular.js:8539
7Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: template/tooltip/tooltip-popup.html
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$compile/tpload?p0=template%2Ftooltip%2Ftooltip-popup.html
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.js:78:12
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.js:6900:17
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.js:8098:11
    at wrappedErrback (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.js:11555:78)
    at wrappedErrback (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.js:11555:78)
    at wrappedErrback (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.js:11555:78)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.js:11688:76
    at Scope.$eval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.js:12658:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.js:12470:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.js:12762:24)
```

Comment: Please delete this question.  As I mentioned, I inherited this project, and for some reason, it had a line that deleted everything out of the template cache.  Couldn't believe it.

Comment: Oh, and for the record, you do NOT need to inject ui.bootstrap.tpls into your app.  ui.bootstrap does that.  Simple include the tpls js file not the ui.bootstrap...js.

Answer (score 29):

I just wanna post my solution for this error.

1. include the *tpls* version of ui.bootstrap

src="assets/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"

apparently the none tpls version doesn't include those templates.

2. when you inject it into you app, make sure you inject ui.bootstrap and not ui.bootstrap.modal

   angular.module("shiftPlanner", ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

for more info [rtfm](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/FAQ#im-using-modal-service-but-it-cant-find-its-templates) ;)

Comment: The first option (include the tpls version of ui.bootstrap) worked for me

Answer (score 22):

I had a very similar issue and was able to resolve it thanks to your comment, Glenn. Therefore I would like to wrap this up into a more general answer that is hopefully helpful to many others:

**If UI Bootstrap templates fail to load and you have already double-checked that you have included [the right module from the right JS file](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/FAQ#im-using-modal-service-but-it-cant-find-its-templates) ([and only it](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/852)) into your app, check if the template cache is disabled/broken for some reason.**

There are [multiple ways to disable or clear the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971831/better-way-to-prevent-ie-cache-in-angularjs), and one may not be aware that this is happening at all.

In my case modal dialogs weren't opening with error messages like `Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: template/modal/backdrop.html`.

I had started off from [a great template project](http://www.jboss.org/quickstarts/wfk/kitchensink-angularjs-bootstrap/) downloaded from the JBoss Developer page, which had the following lines included in the app definition:

```
var xpApp = angular.module('kitchensink', ['ui.bootstrap',...])
.config(... {
    /*
     * Use a HTTP interceptor to add a nonce to every request to prevent MSIE from caching responses.
     */
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('ajaxNonceInterceptor');
...

.factory('ajaxNonceInterceptor', function() {
// This interceptor is equivalent to the behavior induced by $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});

var param_start = /\?/;

return {
    request : function(config) {
        if (config.method == 'GET') {
            // Add a query parameter named '_' to the URL, with a value equal to the current timestamp
            config.url += (param_start.test(config.url) ? "&" : "?") + '_=' + new Date().getTime();
            }
            return config;
        }
    }
});
```

Once I removed the interceptor, the modal dialogs were showing.

Comment: Thanks @Joe7! Your answer led me on the proper way to solve a similar issue I have. The HTTP interceptor was the cause. **Instead of removing the interceptor, I added a condition to bypass any url that doesn't start with `/`**

Comment: For an angular newbie, this problem led me to learn $templateCache which I had no idea that existed...

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo I would also like to bypass the interceptor for the bootstrap resources (the urls that don't start with /), can you show me your interceptor ? thanks

Answer (score 5):

I also had this issue but I was only using the tpls version of ui.bootstrap. 
In my case the issue was a cache busting module `ngCacheBuster`.

In the network  tab I could see there was cachebuster parameter at the end of the resource call:

```
/template/window.html?cb=4889764132
```

In this case, bootstrap did not look into its templatecache but decided to load the file from this location, which of course did not exist.

I solved this by whitelisting all calls to the templates  folder from the cachebusting mechanism.

I hope  this will be helpful to anyone experiencing this problem and using cachebusting.

Comment: Took me 5 hours of poking around on a new and unfamiliar project , until I found your post. Thank you  !!

Answer (score 5):

Include **ui.bootstrap.tpls** right below ui.bootstrap

Answer (score 4):

make sure you have included not only ui-bootstrap.js, as well ui-bootstrap-tpls.js

Answer (score 2):

For me it was the interceptor that was producing the error i had to add the below code to make it ignore the calls that are not made to my api:

```
if (config.url.indexOf('templates/') == 0 || config.url.indexOf('uib/') == 0) 
{
   console.log('ignoring '+config.url);
   return config;
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem. You simply state what your issue was. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: sorry for that :) i hope it is better now?

Answer (score 1):

Yep. I solved this issue like this.. and by including ui-bootstrap-tpls.js

```
angular.module('mainModule', ['ui.bootstrap', 'sub-module']);
angular.module('sub-module', ['ui.bootstrap.modal']);
```

However i am not sure if other cases like template-caching will cause the issue or not. At least not for me..