# ui-bootstrap-tpls and ui-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

In my application, I'm using the `$modal` directive of boostrap.ui. I'm also using the Bootstrap navbar with dropdown functionalities.

I'm having the problem that window.html cannot be found [as described in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26352582/ui-bootstrap-tpls-failed-to-load-template).

The problem in my case is that I have both a `ui-boostrap.js` file and a `ui-bootstrap-tpls` file included (v1.3.2)

[According to this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820625/what-is-the-difference-between-ui-bootstrap-tpls-min-js-and-ui-bootstrap-min-js), I should only need the tpls file.
However, when I remove the boostrap.js file, all the other bootstrap functionalities for the dropdowns in my header are not working anymore.

Is it not possible to have both functionalities  available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UI-Bootstrap library is just an Angular wrapper for core Bootstrap library to remove the dependency of jQuery from the application. From the docs:

> This repository contains a set of native AngularJS directives based on
>   Bootstrap's markup and CSS. As a result no dependency on jQuery or
>   Bootstrap's JavaScript is required.

`ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js` or `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` contains the default template for all the Javascript module shipped by Bootstrap i.e. why it's named `-tpls`.

The other file `ui-bootstrap.min.js` or `ui-bootstrap.js` does not include any templates for the Javascript modules/features.

So you should only include `ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js` or `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` if you are not planning to override any template.

The answer about why dropdown stopped working after removing `bootstrap.js` is that your HTML code is still using the jQuery version of Bootstrap but you should start using the ui-bootstrap version of those modules. Yes, it is possible to include both the Angular version of bootstrap (i.e. `ui-bootstrap.min.js`) and jQuery version of bootstrap (`bootstrap.js`) but it will be extra overhead on the app.

There is no need of jQuery in order to use Bootstrap's Javascript features if you have already included the ui-bootstrap library.

Comment: Thanks,  It seems like I have mad a mess by using jquery.js,  boostrap.js, angular.js and ui-boostrap-tpls.js. I will try to remove the Jquery version.

Comment: Yes, if you are not using jQuery for other than just the Bootstrap, better get rid of it and start using the `ui-bootstrap`. That will also save your app from loading additional data and will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by shashank, all bootstrap elements in bootstrap.js in converted to angular directives in ui-bootstrap-tpls. 
If you simply replace the file it wont work as you expected.

If you changes to ui-bootstrap-tpls then you need to change the corresponding bootstrap components to angular ui directives.