# SPA async calls not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, typescript

I've found similar threads regarding IE9 but not IE11.

I have a SPA built with Angular using TypeScript.

However, my async calls to the WebAPI is not refreshing the data on the front-end. Even when I hit Ctrl+F5 (force refresh), only the data that was active at the first time I entered the site is shown.

What can be the problem? I've removed all console.-references in my TypeScript files.

Example of call:

```
private getPerson(id: number): void {
            this.dataContainer.GetPerson(id).then((data) => this.personDataFetched(data), (errorInfo) => this.serverFail(errorInfo));
        }

private personDataFetched(data: Services.Person): void {
            this.$scope.currentPerson = data; // This data doesn't update even if I force refresh
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16971831/498298

Comment: THANK YOU. I used an answer further below for WebAPI
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26798913/1128364

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hansmaad provided me with a thread which contained the answer.
Look here if you have this problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26798913/1128364