# How delete field of navbar in sql-server and angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, sql-server

I have a navbar containing 4 words (A, B, C, D), when I went to the database and I delete for example (A) by its id, the word (A) deletes in menu but its contents remains displayed, I want deleted also its contents and the page went automatically to the login, how to finish this

controller.js:

```
 User.AccessRole({id:this.user.userId},function (res, req) {
        $scope.listmenu=res;
        console.log( $scope.listmenu);
        //$scope.listmenu.id=remove(listmenu, id);
    });
```

config.js:

```
.state('aaaa', {
            url: "/aaaa",
            controller: "aaaa",
            templateUrl: "views/aaaa/aaaa.html",
            data: { pageTitle: 'aaaa' },
            resolve: {
                loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                        'views/aaaa/aaaa.js',
                        'sweet_alert',
                        'datatables_lazy',
                        'fff'
                    ]);
                }
            },
            data: {
                role: [roles.SuperAdministrateur,roles.Administrateur,roles.Agent], pageTitle: 'aaaa'
  }
    })
```

app.js:

```
  .run(['authService', function (authService) {
                authService.fillAuthData();
            }])
            .run(["$rootScope", "authService", "$state", '$window', function ($rootScope, authService, $state, $window) {
                $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function (event, toState) {
                    var authorizedRoles = toState.data.role;
                    console.log("from app");
                     console.log(authorizedRoles);
                    // authService.authentication.isAuth=true;
                    if (authService.authentication.isAuth && authService.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles)) {
                        if (authService.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles) || authorizedRoles === undefined || authorizedRoles.remove(id)) {
                            console.log("You are authorized");
                         } else {
                        $state.go('error.500');
                        authService.logOut();
                         }
                    } else {

                        $state.go('login');

                        // $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){ authService.logOut(); });
                    }
                });
```

topnavbar.html:

```
 <ul class="clearfix" style="margin-top: 0px">
       <span ng-repeat="item in listmenu" >
           <li> <a href="#!{{item.MenuLink}}" ng-if="item.menu_id!=7"
                   class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-border-right"><center>{{item.designation_menu}}</center></a>
           </li>
        </span>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caching issue in angularJS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892406/caching-issue-in-angularjs-application)

Comment: hi Aleksey, I add function for the cache, but it is not the solution, I think we must delete the cookies for the function