# ng-click on table row does not always fire in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I have a situation where an `ng-click` on a table row with `ng-repeat` inside a modal window. The click event has always fired in Chrome. Only once every so often, the click event does not fire in Internet Explorer 11.

Is this a known issue with any workaround?

Comment: do you get any error messages? are you sure is the row getting the onclick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction: the click event *is* firing, and the ajax call behind it is firing, but the results of the ajax call are IE's cached results rather than the results of the latest query.

I believe the problem is described in this question: 
[Better Way to Prevent IE Cache in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971831/better-way-to-prevent-ie-cache-in-angularjs)