# AngularJS scope in IE not refreshed

Tags: angularjs

I have a on page load REST call to my backend java webservice. The results will be set onto a scope object, then I will do some form submission from my UI to the backend and the result is created in the database.

However, when i refresh the page on IE, the new database record is not retrieved, but it works on Chrome. Is there some sort of caching in IE?

It only appears when i close IE and open it again.

The codes to retrieve the database records:

```
    $http({
        method:'GET',
        url:'api/queries'
    }).success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
        $scope.queries = angular.fromJson(data);
    });
```

Comment: What kind of refresh are you doing? Ctrl-F5?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098430/angular-ie-caching-issue-for-http

Answer (score 1):

Karl got it right, it was simply a IE cache problem and the simple solution is to either set a no cache to the http headers or add in some random time params to have it always fetching new data.