# How to include a config section in all modules in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm wondering if it possible to include a .config section just once and that it affects all modules. Question is related with [caching requests in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19771501/526801), and since I don't want to do this in every module that is making requests, I was wondering if it possible to include a .config section globally...

I've googled quite a lot, look in the Angular tutorial, looked at the NG-book and found nothing on this regard...any idea?

Thanks!

**EDIT: Just added this as a config in the module included in all controllers and it works**

Comment: Have you tested to just configuring httpProvider in your main module? It should be enough.

Comment: Hello tasseKATT, nope I haven't...do you mean that there is some sort of inheritance between modules? I know that works like that with scopes, but not sure about config...

Comment: All used modules are combined into a single app. There is only one injector per app, which is why services from all modules are available. This means there should for example only be one httpProvider as well.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll try it out and see what happens, thanks!

Comment: No problem :) Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: tasseKATT, I've modified this as suggested and it works, if you want to publish an answer I'll mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During bootstrap all modules are combined into one application and a single injector is created for it. Services in Angular are singletons in the sense that they are only created once per injector.

This means that there is only once `$http` service created and its configuration will be global for the entire application.