# Angular navigation gives 'bad request' on getting template

Tags: angularjs, routes, navigation

I'm trying to add routing to my new application where i'm for the first time using Angular.

I have the files or file fragments as described below.

**app.js**

```
'use strict';


var app = angular.module('myApplication', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    //initialize get if not there
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
    }
    //disable IE ajax request caching
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';
}]);

// Setting up clientside routes.
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when(
            '/account/details/:name', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/accountDetails.html',
                controller: 'accountDetailsController'
            })
        .when(
            '/account', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/accountOverview.html',
                controller: 'accountController'
            })
        .when(
            '/temp', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/temp.html',
                controller: 'noneController'
            })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/account'
        });
}]);
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApplication">
<head>
  ....
</head>
<body>
  @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div ng-controller="AccountsController">
    <a href="#/account/details/jack">Jack</a>
<div>

<div ng-view />
```

**controllers.js**

```
'use strict';


var app = angular.module('myApplication');


app.controller('accountsController', ['$scope', 'dataService', function ($scope, dataService) {
        // Add some data retrieval here.
    }]);


app.controller('accountDetailsController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'dataService', function ($scope, $routeParams, dataService) {
        // Add some data retrieval here.
}]);
```

When i open the application i see a request is made to retrieve 'templates/accountOverview.html' like expected due to the 'otherwise' in the configuration of $routeprovider.
The url used by this request works, i can open this url in the browser to open the file. But when Angular is opening the file Angular receives a '400 (Bad Request)'.

One big difference between the requests the the 'Accept' header.
 Browser request: Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
 Angular request: Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*

What is going on here? Why is Angular requesting either json or plain text for it's templates and why does my server respond with a HTTP_400? How can i fix this?

Been searching for some time now but it feels like i'm the only one having this issue :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the following line of code was my problem.

```
//disable IE ajax request caching
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';
```

(source for this line was triggered by another problemen: [Angular IE Caching issue for $http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098430/angular-ie-caching-issue-for-http))

Better lines are

```
//disable IE ajax request caching
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT';
```

or possibly

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
```

Comment: its work for me as well, I am finding solution from last 5 hours. Thanks @Svenl