# angularjs IE Cache buster works, but breaks directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, caching

I have had a problem with IE caching everything, so if i switched user, i would still see data from the old user which is not logged in anymore.

I tried this solution (found at : [Angular IE Caching issue for $http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098430/angular-ie-caching-issue-for-http) ), and it worked but now my directive can't GET the template it needs, how can i get both things to work ?

code:

```
   app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    //initialize get if not there
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
    }
    console.log($httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since']);

    //disable IE ajax request caching
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';
}]);
```

My directive:

```
app.directive('commentsContainer', function (commentResource, signalRService) {
return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    templateUrl: '/Templates/Directives/_Comments.html',
    link: function ($scope) {
         //CODE
    }
}
```

**EDIT!**
it get an error no matter which browser, here is the one from chrome :

```
GET http://localhost:58991/Templates/Directives/_Comments.html 400 (Bad Request) 

Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /Templates/Directives/_Comments.html
```

Without the angular snippit for caching, it works fine..

Hope you can help!

Comment: What do you mean "cant", are you getting an error? Does it make the request? Note that IE does not have a `console` unless you actually have the console open so that can cause it to break.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Ill add the error. my bad

Comment: Try to add these headers: `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'; $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';`

Comment: Well, it seems to work. But i had to delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the resource you provided there is two possible fixes.

First solution in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098430/angular-ie-caching-issue-for-http#comment32597432_19771501) by [Langdon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158502/langdon)

> The If-Modified-Since header makes IIS+iisnode throw 400 Bad Request
>   for every html file loaded through ngInclude and ngView. The following
>   two headers fixed the issue for me though (I pulled them from Chrome,
>   which didn't have the caching issue):
>
> $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
>   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';

Second solution in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098430/angular-ie-caching-issue-for-http#comment37677253_19771501) by [lopisan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2203164/lopisan)

> The usage of If-Modified-Since = "0" header breaks Tomcat (Problem
>   with parsing header date, as 0 is not valid value RFC). Fixed using
>   value 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT' instead.

Comment: Both suggestions caused Angular to throw an error, and my webpage to not render properly  (I'd still see curly brackets on the page, rather than Angular-binded values..)