# Angular js displays just expression in chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am developing a portal using ASP.NET MVC plus AngularJS. Everything is working as expected. However, intermittently during development, when I refresh the page, I just see the angular expressions as below (in both chrome and IE 9).

I initially thought it to be a caching issue, and have disabled caching using $httpProvider as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19771501/197868).

Any idea what is the root cause for this behaviour and how to resolve the same.

[image]

Comment: any errors showing up in the console?

Comment: No errors in console. I use console extensively for debugging and logs, I do not see any.

Comment: Do you mean that those angular expressions appear only until angular evaluates them? or do they remain even after everything loads?

Comment: they remain even after load. basically page just stops. if I hit F5, everything is fine. It is very intermittent. It may not be angularjs problem at all. May be I need to uninstall all the chrome extensions and try it. I have angular batarang and ngInspector extensions.

Comment: that has happened to me a few times when I changed my javascript files. Basically, yes, hard refresh usually helps

Comment: Okay! At least I'm not alone. Just wanted to know th  root cause. Not a blocking issue for me though..

Comment: Try to use the attribute ng-bind instead of expression.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that, this is due to console.* statements I had in my JS. Apparently IE does not handle those statements gracefully and throws the error. Hence, AngularJS is not processed. However, console.* statements are executed fine when IE developer tools are active (i.e you have kept it open).

I [blogged](http://www.visualstudiogeeks.com/blog/angularjs/mvc/ie/angularjs-and-ie9) about the issues I faced (specific to IE) and how I resolved those. From the blog post, this specific issue is addressed under Issue 2 (AngularJS does not execute or executes only when IE developer tools are enabled)