# AngularJS post returning status code 304 instead of posting to play backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, yeoman, http-status-code-304

I have created a simple form with as below

controller is as below

```
angular.module('clientApp')
   .controller('SignupCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $log, alertService, $location, userService) {

     $scope.signup = function() {
       var payload = {
         email : $scope.email,
         password : $scope.password
       };

       $http.post('app/signup', payload)
           .error(function(data, status) {
             if(status === 400) {
               angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                 if(key === 'email' || key === 'password') {
                   alertService.add('danger', key + ' : ' + value);
                 } else {
                   alertService.add('danger', value.message);
                 }
               });
             }
             if(status === 500) {
               alertService.add('danger', 'Internal server error!');
             }
           })

     };
   });
```

My view is as below.

```
<form name="signupForm" ng-submit="signup()" novalidate>
 <div>
   <label for="email">Email</label>
   <input name="email" class="form-control" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"
          ng-model="email">
   </div>
 <div>
   <label for="password">Password</label>
   <input name="password" class="form-control" type="password" id="password"
          placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">

 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up!</button>
</form>
```

my index is as below

```
//js files
<!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

My app.js

```
angular
  .module('tripApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.bootstrap'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .when('/signup', {
        templateUrl: 'views/signup.html',
        controller: 'SignupCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

When I do a post I get 304 GET response while posting to the server. Also its appending the input characters to the site url which i don't like since it a POST. Please advice.

Comment: Well, probably it's better to have a look to the server side code who responds 304. Client side I don't see particular issues.

Comment: Follow this thread for answers
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098430/angular-ie-caching-issue-for-http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

304 means "Not Modified" - content is cached.

Try adding "cache: false" in your $http config.

I would also recommend that you verify "app/signup" is not cached (sometimes you can set it per method)