# Disable cache in all browsers

Tags: c#, angularjs, caching, xmlhttprequest

Is it enough to set `cache:false` in my `$http` or I should add other configurations too?

```
var self = this;
self.get = function () {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        url: '.......'
    });
}
```

Comment: No, caching response data in browsers. I have some problems in my project functionality, since the user may see the cached data in his page, not the real data.

Comment: You should not include tags in question title. [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers?rq=1

Comment: Related: [Angular IE Caching issue for $http](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098430/angular-ie-caching-issue-for-http)