# ng-repeat does not display new data in IE 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I develop an application with AngularJS, when I add a new element called a POLCOM, the list of POLCOM remains the same without the new item. this problem appears only in IE11 in chrome no problem.

this is my service:

```js
listPOLCOM : function(succes,error) {
  return $http.get('/polcom').then(succes,error);
}
```

this my controller:

```js
servicePolcom.listPOLCOM(
    function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.listPolcom = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert("error");
    });
```

this is my HTML:

```html
<tr data-ng-repeat="polcom in listPolcom">

        <td>{{ polcom.libelle }}</td>
        <td>{{ polcom.startDate }}</td>
        <td>{{ polcom.endDate }}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in IE's console? Maybe try adding some cache busting, something like `$http.get('/polcom', { params: { _: Date.now() } }).then(success, error)`

Comment: No any errors in IE's console

Comment: IE is known for caching AJAX GET requests. Try the above cache busting as a test or for a more permanent solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098430/angular-ie-caching-issue-for-http

Comment: the problem into the solution that you sent me is that to put the config Module must have the hand at the entrance to the application, which is not the case in my case because I use a framwork that called seedstack that allows you to create that service and controller and hide you to enter