# .NET MVC What is the best way to disable browser caching?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, browser-cache

As far as my research goes, there are several steps in order to make sure that browser caching is disabled. These HTTP headers must be set:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Last-Modified: -1
```

I have found out that this can be done in two ways:

**Way One: use the web.config file**

```
<add name="Cache-Control" value="no-store, no-cache, 
    must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"/>
<add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
<add name="Expires" value="-1" />
<add name="Last-Modified" value="-1" />
```

**Way Two: use the meta tags in _Layout.cshtml**

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store,
    must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
```

My Question: which is the better approach? Or, alternatively, are they equally acceptable? How do these all relate to different platforms? Which browsers would honor what headers?

In addition, please feel free to add anything I've missed, if any.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011780/prevent-caching-in-asp-net-mvc-for-specific-actions-using-an-attribute

Comment: @Murali did you post that comment manually or did you retract your close vote?

Comment: @Stijn, I posted it manually and i didn't vote for close this :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay folks, seems I made a blunt mistake. There **is** a best way and that is **not** using meta tags. The **only** correct way is to use headers.

- Why not use meta tags? Because they are guaranteed not to work with
  proxies, which do not read (not supposed to read) the HTML body; they
  rely on the headers.
- When both Cache-Control and Expires are present, Cache-Control takes
  precedence. [Source here](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).
- Cache-Control general-header field is used to specify directives that
  MUST be obeyed by all caching mechanisms along the request/response
  chain. [Source here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9).