# Prevent LoggedOut users from viewing user-only-pages from browser history

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC (5) application, session is not being used to identify whether a user is logged in or not. Rather, I'm using some encrypted values in query strings or hidden fields.

But just now I realized that any person can visit those user-only-pages from browser history.

Any idea to solve this problem?

UPDATE: Most of the MVC Actions send partial html/json through ajax.

UPDATE:

```
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(); // I want it from viewing from browser cache.
    }
```

Comment: "Rather, I'm using some encrypted values in query strings or hidden fields." - this sounds horrifyingly insecure to me....

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable caching on the pages that require an authenticated user, e.g.

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

Also see: [Prevent Caching in ASP.NET MVC for specific actions using an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011780/prevent-caching-in-asp-net-mvc-for-specific-actions-using-an-attribute)

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you implemented that and what exactly it is doing?

Comment: @SKPaul How does your view determine if a user is logged in or not, and what does it do when it determines that the user is or is not logged in?