# Ajax call gets cached, despite the appropriate parameter

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm currently writing a MVC C# application. Everything works just fine. I have a bit of functionality, where I fill up a Bootstrap modal box using an Ajax call, but the new page gets cached, despite my efforts to prevent that.

On my main page I have the following actionhandler to fill up the modal box:

```
function setExtraPermsOrAtts(appID){
    $.ajax({
        cache:false,
        url: "/Group/_modifyAppPermissionsOfGroup?appID=" + appID            
    }).done(function (result) {
        $("#addApplicationBody").html(result);
        $('#modal-add-application').modal('show');
    });
}
```

This gets caught by the following method:

```
    public ActionResult _modifyAppPermissionsOfGroup(int? appID = 0)
    {
        if (appID != 0)
        {
            ViewBag.selectedAppID = appID;
            Session["selectedGroupAppID"] = appID;
            ViewBag.modifyPermsLater = true;
        }
        Group group = (Group)Session["currentGroup"];
        return View(group);
    }
```

Another thing that might be relevant is the point where it 'goes wrong'. The resulting View in the Modalbox, has a few radio buttons, depending on the content of the database. There I do a razor statement to get the DB value:

```
bool valueOfRadButtons = BusinessLogic.Domain.GroupIS.getExistingGroupPermission( 
                 Model.LoginGroupID, myItem.ApplicationPermissionID).LoginPermissionState;
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? Is it the Ajax call? The ActionResult method in the Controller? Or the inline razor statement? I know the data gets saved properly, cause I see so in the DB

Comment: `cache: false` adds a dummy time-stamp parameter to the URL to "ensure" the request is unique (and not cached). You could change it to a `post` (which never caches), or better yet add cache attributes to the `_modifyAppPermissionsOfGroup` server method to stop any caching. e.g. `[OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]`

Comment: I added the OutputCacheAttribute annotation to my ActionResult method, but that doesn't work. The valueOfRadButtons variable still gets cached.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify that the response shouldn't be cached like this:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

It can be more easy if you make your own attribute and decorate the action with it as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011780/prevent-caching-in-asp-net-mvc-for-specific-actions-using-an-attribute).