# MVC 4 website back press return the same form with old values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in MVC 4 web development and i am creating a control panel. I have developed a Add user page and submit information in database successfully.
But after submit when i press back button it will show previous form.
i am using redirection the page to same page after submit form.
here is the code to redirect

```
public ActionResult AdminPanel(RegisterUserModel user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) // Check the model state for any validation errors
        {       
            if (user.AddUserToDB(user.username, user.password, user.fullName,user.contactNo,user.COAId)) // Calls the Login class checkUser() for existence of the user in the database.
            {

                TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "User Added Sucessfully!";
                ModelState.Clear();
                return Redirect("AdminPanel");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "User Not Added";
                return View();
            }
        }

            SelectList clientsList = GetClinetList();

            ViewBag.clientsList = clientsList;



            return View(); // Return the same view with validation errors.

    }
```

I have tried many examples but issue not resolved yet so kindly give my suggesstions

Comment: I don't think that anyone can answer this question without getting more details (code). Maybe give us a minimalistic example.

Comment: i have added my actionMethod

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the user to be able to see the previous content when clicking back, then you must indicate that content should not be cached by the browser and must revalidate with the origin server

A summary of this behaviour is here - http://blog.55minutes.com/2011/10/how-to-defeat-the-browser-back-button-cache/

You could create a nocache attribute, like this one - https://stackoverflow.com/a/10011896/1538039, and apply it to your controller methods.

Comment: i cant understand where should i use these methods ?
should i use on my action method?

Comment: Yes, on your GET action method that returns the form view