# CSS transparent background image using "data:"

Tags: image, base64, background-image, css

I've seen on some sites that you can include images in CSS using a "data" keyword:

```
.stuff {
  background: transparent url(data:image/gif;base64,SOMEWEIRDCODEHERE) repeat center top;
}
```

the weird code looks like a base64 ecoded string like:

> R0lGODlhMwAxAIAAAAAAAP///
>   yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAzADEAAAK8jI+pBr0PowytzotTtbm/DTqQ6C3hGX
>   ElcraA9jIr66ozVpM3nseUvYP1UEHF0FUUHkNJxhLZfEJNvol06tzwrgd
>   LbXsFZYmSMPnHLB+zNJFbq15+SOf50+6rG7lKOjwV1ibGdhHYRVYVJ9Wn
>   k2HWtLdIWMSH9lfyODZoZTb4xdnpxQSEF9oyOWIqp6gaI9pI1Qo7BijbF
>   ZkoaAtEeiiLeKn72xM7vMZofJy8zJys2UxsCT3kO229LH1tXAAAOw==

look pretty cool :D

I was wondering how can I include a transparent 1x1 pixel GIF like this? Does anyone know the data code for such a image?

Is it a good idea to do this for small and very common images? Do all browsers support this?

Comment: Unless there's something I'm not aware of, there's no reason to use a spacer gif as a CSS background image.

Comment: Hi Ben. I'm trying to make the line numbers here unselectable: http://jsfiddle.net/rVwqR/

Comment: Just prevent selection like this via CSS; no background image needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting/4407335#4407335

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work in opera

Comment: See also [smallest filesize for transparent single pixel image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570633/smallest-filesize-for-transparent-single-pixel-image)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's called the [The data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Use the **Data URI Kitchen** to convert just about anything to data uri's. Link:
http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/data/data

Comment: @Alex: Yes, that's because the image is transparent no? Either way, once you convert, copy the url in the address bar. Should start with `data`.

Comment: @Alex: Make sure `Base64` is **checked** on the page I linked to above if you want to use Base64 (it's usually shorter that what it normally gives if it's unchecked);)

Comment: thanks. it's still big, but I removed the metadata added by photoshop and it's small now. but it I can only disable selection under this image in FF and chrome. Opera still is able to select :x

Answer (score 15):

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==
```

Nothing wrong with doing this, you save an HTTP round-trip.  The only downside is that it doesn't work in older versions of IE (IE8, I believe, started to support it)

Answer (score 8):

this is a transparent GIF of one pixel

```
background-image: url( data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw== );
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the browsers you need to support you might be better off using `rgba()`. I know this question is a little old.

```
body {
  background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .5 ); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Up-to-date browser support details for data URIs:

**http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri**