# Blank image encoded as data-uri

Tags: html, web-standards, data-uri

I've built an image slider (based on the terrific [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/)) which will preload images just-in-time before they slide into view. It's working pretty well already, but I don't think my solution is valid HTML.

My technique is as follows: I generate the slider markup with the first slide image being inserted as usual (with an `<img src="foo.jpg">`) and subsequent images being referenced in a data attribute like `<img data-orig="bar.jpg">`.  A Javascript then juggles the `data-orig -> src` change when necessary, triggering the preloading.

In other words, I have:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div><img src="time.jpg" /></div> 
    <div><img src="data:" data-orig="fastelavn.jpg" /></div> 
    <div><img src="data:" data-orig="pels_strik.jpg" /></div> 
    <div><img src="data:" data-orig="fashion.jpg" /></div> 
</div>
```

To avoid empty `src=""` attributes (which are [harmful to performance](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/11/30/empty-image-src-can-destroy-your-site/) in [some browsers](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/07/13/empty-string-urls-browser-update/)), I've inserted `src="data:"` to effectively insert a blank image as a placeholder.

The thing is, I can't seem to find anything in the [documentation for data-URI](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2397.html) saying whether this is a valid data-URI or not. I basically want the minimal data-URI that resolves to a blank/transparent image, so the browser can resolve the src immediately and move on (with no error or network request). Maybe `src="data:image/gif;base64,"` would be better?

Comment: Just use empty hash. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28077004/3841049

Comment: @iGidas: bad idea, as many browsers will actually make a second request to the main page (causing a far worse performance hit than the original image and creating confusing entries in your server logs), try to interpret the HTML as an image, throw an error, and potentially cause real application errors (e.g. in shopping carts / checkout pages where the 'page refresh' causes more items to be added in the basket or triggers security measures)

Comment: What about the actual `data:image/gif;base64,` used as an `src`? Or even shorter `data:,` ending with a coma. Seems to be valid HTML and working in every modern browser without any errors. Any arguments against using it?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

I looked into it and the [smallest possible transparent GIF image](http://probablyprogramming.com/2009/03/15/the-tiniest-gif-ever), encoded as a data-uri, was this:

`data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==`

which is what I'm using now.

Comment: If your `img` element is already hidden and you're just trying to avoid HTTP 404 errors, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14115340/14731 for a shorter data of a non-transparent image.

Answer (score 46):

If you need a transparent image 1x1 pixel, just set this data uri as `src` default attribute (keep the `///` parts, it encodes byte 255, not a comment).

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==
```

This is instead a base64 encoding for an image 1x1 white.

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP7//wAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==
```

Otherwise you could set `data:null` and save ~60 extra bytes for each image.

Comment: Can you provide a link to verify that data:null is valid as an image source?

Comment: @JensRoland, empty data is valid as per this Mozilla KB: http://www-archive.mozilla.org/quality/networking/testing/datatests.html
But the non-image is not rendered, so any alt attributes fall through.

Comment: @K3---rnc: I saw that list from Mozilla; unfortunately, that is not the spec, merely the expected behavior for Mozilla testers; in other words, it reflects Mozillas interpretation of the spec. It's a good sign, but it offers little assurance that any version of IE or Webkit will behave the same.

Comment: @fcalderan I am curious, why did you offer a white version since both are the same size? Does the white offer any advantage over the transparent?

Answer (score 28):

```
data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"/>
```

Valid and highly compressible. Essentially free if there's another inline svg in the page.

Comment: I like this one. I see only two weaknesses: First, SVG is not supported in IE<9 (not usually a problem, but it does make it infeasible for some sites); and second, "SVG data needs to be uriencoded to work in IE and Firefox" (see http://caniuse.com/#search=datauri), so you actually have to use: `data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22/%3E` which is still 4 bytes shorter than mine, but it does look a bit messy

Answer (score 27):

## The smallest I've ever seen

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=
```

**update:** This seems broken and doesn't work anymore as reported by @bryc, please use the other answers.

Comment: Sure, except that one is Chrome only. Open it in Firefox and you'll get `The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors`. See http://proger.i-forge.net/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80/[20121112]%20The%20smallest%20transparent%20pixel.html

Comment: @JensRoland,  yeah right I confirm it's not working on Firefox! though when using it over a year ago I don't remember any problem with FF! weird

Comment: @JensRoland That link solved it for me. I needed a transparent PNG: if you change the opacity on an img whose src is the clear gif, when you reset opacity, the clearness is glitched.

Comment: This doesn't work in Chrome either. If you open `data:image/gif;base64,R0` directly in Chrome and compare it with this answer, it shows the same 'broken' 16x16 image. Thus you are fooling yourself into thinking Chrome is rendering it correctly as a 1x1 transparent GIF.

Comment: @bryc, It seems that is completely true, though I have used this 5 years ago and back then it was working or I've been mistakenly thought it's working.  therefore everyone now should use https://stackoverflow.com/a/19891866/3160597 I guess

Comment: @azerafati That one is better, but it is **white** in FF and blank in Chrome, which can be an issue if used on a non-white BG. It's also not futureproof as it strips one byte required by most image software. Like you said, what worked then doesn't work anymore... I had an even shorter 14B one that worked back then only in Chrome, which stopped working. Check out this answer here that demystifies the lot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15960901/815680. I use a 32B version that is transparent everywhere. :D cheers

Answer (score 16):

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAA=
```

is smaller :D

Comment: True -- that one is adorable! But is it a standard compliant gif? Could you elaborate on how you arrived at it?

Comment: http://proger.i-forge.net/The_smallest_transparent_pixel/eBQ

Comment: The link states that both this and the 14-byte one are for Chrome only, and that there is no guarantee that it will work across all browsers. Furthermore, the resulting gif doesn't seem to open in any image editor. So I'd be hesitant to use it.

Comment: @JensRoland adding one missing byte (LZW header byte) will make it open in most image editors (change `=` to `C`). It is black in PS/Paint/Gimp, white in Firefox, transparent in Chrome, due to no color information present and it is up to the software to decide the default.

Answer (score 9):

1px by 1px JPEG image

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

Comment: Can be significantly smaller: `/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAP//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////wAALCAABAAEBAREA/8QAJgABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAxABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/aAAgBAQAAPwBH/9k`. But if you want a white 1x1 square, might as well use GIF: `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAAC`

Answer (score 5):

Fabrizio's "white gif" isn't actually perfectly white : it is `rgb(254, 255, 255)`.

I use the following one (which happens to be smaller), found on [this page](http://proger.i-forge.net/The_smallest_transparent_pixel/eBQ).

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=
```

Comment: That one is fine if you want a white pixel, but I was looking for a more general-purpose transparent one.