# Unable to generate PDF file with '0x' varbinary value ASP.net itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, pdf, itext

I have developed a webapp which is able to generate PDF files. The users have the choice to upload up to 5 pictures. When the users uploaded 5 pictures, I will then be able to generate the PDF file. However, if the users only chooses to upload 4, i will not be able to generated the PDF file and i will receive this error.

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array
```

I have inserted a default value '0x' as varbinary if the user does not upload all 5 pictures. This is the code on how i get my images directly from my SQL server.

```
phrase.Add(new Chunk("C-IMG1 :\u00a0", normalFont));
            Byte[] bytes1 = (Byte[])dr[8];
            iTextSharp.text.Image image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes1);
            image1.ScaleToFit(112f, 112f);
            Chunk imageChunk1 = new Chunk(image1, 0, 0);
            phrase.Add(imageChunk1);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("C-IMG2 :\u00a0", normalFont));
            Byte[] bytes2 = (Byte[])dr[9];
            iTextSharp.text.Image image2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes2);
            image2.ScaleToFit(112f, 112f);
            Chunk imageChunk2 = new Chunk(image2, 0, 0);
            phrase.Add(imageChunk2);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("C-IMG3 :\u00a0", normalFont));
            Byte[] bytes3 = (Byte[])dr[10];
            iTextSharp.text.Image image3 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes3);
            image3.ScaleToFit(112f, 112f);
            Chunk imageChunk3 = new Chunk(image3, 0, 0);
            phrase.Add(imageChunk3);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("C-IMG4 :\u00a0", normalFont));
            Byte[] bytes4 = (Byte[])dr[11];
            iTextSharp.text.Image image4 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes4);
            image4.ScaleToFit(112f, 112f);
            Chunk imageChunk4 = new Chunk(image4, 0, 0);
            phrase.Add(imageChunk4);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("C-IMG5 :\u00a0", normalFont));
            Byte[] bytes5 = (Byte[])dr[12];
            iTextSharp.text.Image image5 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes5);
            image5.ScaleToFit(112f, 112f);
            Chunk imageChunk5 = new Chunk(image5, 0, 0);
            phrase.Add(imageChunk5);
```

How do i solve this? Have been stuck for a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking iTextSharp to create an image from empty bytes which will result in an error, you'll need to add some code to handle the empty image case. I posted in [your other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310875/different-picture-size-in-pdf-despite-having-same-resolution-scaletofit-asp-n) that I recommend switching to a `PdfPTable` for this which would make your life easier. But if you're going to continue down the `Phrase`/`Chunk` path then either have SQL Server return a valid "default image" if an image isn't found or have your code insert a "default image".

For instance, from SQL Server you could just return the [smallest transparent image possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570633/smallest-filesize-for-transparent-single-pixel-image) which if I converted it correctly would be:

```
0x47494638396101000100800000ffffff00000021f90400000000002c00000000010001000002024401003b
```

Or from .Net you could just generate a simple blank image or load one from disk.

Also, you're code could be simplified if you just moved everything into a loop:

```
//Loop through the 5 images
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //Output the image with the current index (adding 1 since we're starting at zero)
    phrase.Add(new Chunk("C-IMG" + (i + 1).ToString() + " :\u00a0", normalFont));
    //It appears 8 is the "magic number" of the column so add whatever index we're currently on
    Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dr[8 + i];
    if (bytes.Length == 0) {
        //Do something special with the empty ones
    } else {
        iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes);
        image.ScaleToFit(112f, 112f);
        Chunk imageChunk = new Chunk(image, 0, 0);
        phrase.Add(imageChunk);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have pasted my entire code in the another thread. I did use pdfptable. I used the chunk because i'm not able to format the size of the picture or the font size of the words if i were to get my data via  datareader.