# How do I add cell in my pdftable and insert pictures into it

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I'm trying to create a pdf with 10 images. All these 10 images can be retrieved directly from the database by using this method below.

This are the codes that i used to create a PdfPTable to insert my data inside.

```
    protected void btnPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var doc1 = new Document();
        var filename = "MyTestPDF" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".pdf";
        var output = new FileStream(Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\apr13mpsip\\Downloads", filename), FileMode.Create);
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, output);
        doc1.Open();


        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);

        table.TotalWidth = 585f;
        table.LockedWidth = true;


        PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(1);
        table2.TotalWidth = 585f;
        table2.LockedWidth = true;

        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell imgCell1 = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell();

        var logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/image/logo.jpg"));
        doc1.Add(logo);

        var titleFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 15, Font.BOLD);
        doc1.Add(new Paragraph("Official Report. Member Report ID : " + DDLCase.SelectedValue, titleFont));

        var normalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 14, Font.BOLD);
        var phrase = new Phrase();
        var phrase2 = new Phrase();
```

This is my database connection codes where i link my SQL server database with my project.

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security = SSPI");

        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select lro.fullname, lro.contact, mr.typeofcrime, mr.location,mr.crdatetime, mr.citizenreport, pr.policeid,  pr.prdatetime, pr.policereport, aor.officialreport,  mr.image1, mr.image2, mr.image3, mr.image4, mr.image5,  pr.image1, pr.image2, pr.image3, pr.image4, pr.image5 from MemberReport mr, PoliceReport pr, LoginRegisterOthers lro, AdminOfficialReport aor where mr.memberreportid = '" + DDLCase.SelectedValue + "' and mr.memberreportid=pr.memberreportid and pr.policereportid=aor.policereportid", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr;

        dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
```

This is how i used datareader to read the data in my SQL server and retrieve the respective images and information that will be generated and displayed into the PDF.

```
 if (dr.Read())
        {

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Full Name :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[0].ToString());

            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Contact :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[1].ToString());

            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Type Of Crime :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[2].ToString());

            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Location :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[3].ToString());

            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Citizen Report Date Time :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[4].ToString());

            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Citizen Report :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[5].ToString());

            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Citizen Images :", normalFont));

            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("1.", normalFont));
            Byte[] bytes1 = (Byte[])dr[10];
            iTextSharp.text.Image image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes1);
            image1.ScaleToFit(850f, 850f);
            image1.SetDpi(96,96);
            Chunk imageChunk1 = new Chunk(image1, 0, 0);
            phrase.Add(imageChunk1);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("2.", normalFont));
            Byte[] bytes5 = (Byte[])dr[11];
            iTextSharp.text.Image image5 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes5);
            image5.ScaleToFit(850f, 850f);
            image5.SetDpi(96, 96);
            Chunk imageChunk5 = new Chunk(image5, 0, 0);
            phrase.Add(imageChunk5);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("3.", normalFont));
            Byte[] bytes6 = (Byte[])dr[12];
            iTextSharp.text.Image image6 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes6);
            image6.ScaleToFit(850f, 850f);
            image6.SetDpi(96, 96);
            Chunk imageChunk6 = new Chunk(image6, 0, 0);
            phrase.Add(imageChunk6);

            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("4.", normalFont));
            Byte[] bytes7 = (Byte[])dr[13];
            iTextSharp.text.Image image7 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes7);
            image7.SetDpi(96,96);
            image7.ScaleToFit(2067f, 2064f);
            Chunk imageChunk7 = new Chunk(image7, 0, 0);
            phrase.Add(imageChunk7);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("5.", normalFont));
            Byte[] bytes8 = (Byte[])dr[14];
            iTextSharp.text.Image image8 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes8);
            image8.ScaleToFit(2067f, 2064f);
            image8.SetDpi(96, 96);
            Chunk imageChunk8 = new Chunk(image8, 0, 0);
            phrase.Add(imageChunk8);

            //phrase2.Add(new Chunk("Police ID :", normalFont));
            //phrase2.Add(dr[6].ToString());

            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            //phrase2.Add(new Chunk("Police Report Date Time :", normalFont));
            //phrase2.Add(dr[7].ToString());

            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            //phrase2.Add(new Chunk("Police Report :", normalFont));
            //phrase2.Add(dr[8].ToString());

            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            //phrase2.Add(new Chunk("Official Report :", normalFont));
            //phrase2.Add(dr[9].ToString());

            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            //phrase2.Add(new Chunk("Police Images :", normalFont));

            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            //phrase2.Add(new Chunk("1 :\u00a0", normalFont));
            //Byte[] bytes10 = (Byte[])dr[15];
            //iTextSharp.text.Image image10 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes10);
            //image10.ScaleToFit(850f, 850f);
            //image5.SetDpi(1024, 768);
            //Chunk imageChunk10 = new Chunk(image10, 0, 0);
            //phrase2.Add(imageChunk10);

            //phrase2.Add(new Chunk("2 :\u00a0", normalFont));
            //Byte[] bytes11 = (Byte[])dr[16];
            //iTextSharp.text.Image image11 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes11);
            //image11.ScaleToFit(850f, 850f);
            //image5.SetDpi(1024, 768);
            //Chunk imageChunk11 = new Chunk(image11, 0, 0);
            //phrase2.Add(imageChunk11);


            //phrase2.Add(new Chunk("3 :\u00a0", normalFont));
            //Byte[] bytes12 = (Byte[])dr[17];
            //iTextSharp.text.Image image12 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes12);
            //image12.ScaleToFit(850f, 850f);
            //image5.SetDpi(1024, 768);
            //Chunk imageChunk12 = new Chunk(image12, 0, 0);
            //phrase2.Add(imageChunk12);

            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            //phrase2.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            //phrase2.Add(new Chunk("4 :\u00a0", normalFont));
            //Byte[] bytes13 = (Byte[])dr[18];
            //iTextSharp.text.Image image13 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes13);
            //image13.ScaleToFit(850f, 850f);
            //image5.SetDpi(1024, 768);
            //Chunk imageChunk13 = new Chunk(image13, 0, 0);
            //phrase2.Add(imageChunk13);

            //phrase2.Add(new Chunk("5 :\u00a0", normalFont));
            //Byte[] bytes14 = (Byte[])dr[19];
            //iTextSharp.text.Image image14 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes14);
            //image14.ScaleToFit(850f, 850f);
            //image5.SetDpi(1024, 768);
            //Chunk imageChunk14 = new Chunk(image14, 0, 0);
            //phrase2.Add(imageChunk14);



            table.AddCell(phrase);
            //table2.AddCell(phrase2);

        }

        dr.Close();
        doc1.Add(table);
        doc1.NewPage();
        doc1.Add(table2);
        doc1.Close();
    }


}
}
```

I also have a `PdfPTable` which only has one column and I wasn't able to add cell to allocate specific image into specific cell.

As you can see I retrieve my image directly from my SQL database hence I believe it would be even harder to add the image into respective cell.

Here's a few of my [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336499/maintain-similiar-image-size-in-pdf-using-itextsharp) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310875/different-picture-size-in-pdf-despite-having-same-resolution-scaletofit-asp-n) about the thread i have posted which all have picture alignment problem. The links provided above all have pictures that shows big alignment problems. Hence, the only way i can think of to align the picture properly is to add a cell and place the image into respective cells. I hope to have pictures that are aligned side by side with the same size.

Comment: It's really not clear what the question is. Is the commmented code relevant to your question? You mention PdfPTable and access from a database, but there's nothing about that in the code you show. Please try to come down to a shorter, more complete code sample. Also, an example of what you want to achieve, compared to what you have so far, would be really useful.

Comment: I have editted the question above. I have added 2 links to the different thread i have posted regarding similiar question which no one knows how to reply. The links all contain pictures and different codes on the different alignment problem i faced. Hence, i rephrase and rethink my question in order to get more response.

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing something like this earlier. Where your image byte array from the database goes into the GetInstance at Image.

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagebytearray);
PdfPcell cell = new PdfPCell(image);
table.AddCell(cell);
```

Comment: Then how do i align it and specify a position and size? I only know how to do it with image chunk though.

Comment: For the cell alignment: cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT; and the image: image.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;. Was this what you ment?

Answer (score 0):

For the picture size: image.ScaleToFit()