# infinite scroll without loading image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, infinite-scroll

I have looked everywhere to try and figure out how to use infinite scroll and not have a loading image, but I cannot find it. This is how you set it up loading text and image:

```
loading: {
    img: "/img/loading.gif",
    msgText: "Loading new posts..."
}
```

if i set `msgText` to `''` then there will be no text, yet I cannot seem to do the same with the loading image as if I set it to a blank string, it will display the error image image.

**How can I use infinite scroll with no loading image?**

## [infinite-scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/)

note that the loading image and text is incorrect syntax on that page, you can see the correct syntax [here](http://www.tonylea.com/2012/infinite-scroll-loading-image-and-text/)

Comment: Use a blank image? Like a transparent 1x1 png

Comment: that's an annoying little hack though...could work and I will do it if I have to, but I think it's stupid if there really is no way to not have a loading image...

Comment: This is a plugin? What is the name.

Comment: Well you haven't given any information about the framework you're using. Obviously if you get a missing image error when you remove the img property then you need to edit your class/object to allow empty or no image property.

Comment: I would rather not have to edit infinite scroll although I can if I have t...I provided all links to documentation, although they don't help with what I am asking as I have gone into depth searching...I was just wondering if anybody knows a quick way around it

Answer (score 9):

You could use a base64 encoded 1x1 pixel transparent image:

```
img: 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=='
```

This way you avoid sending lots of headers to download a tiny image.

---

**Edit**:
From [smallest filesize for transparent single pixel image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570633/smallest-filesize-for-transparent-single-pixel-image), you could also use the shorter

```
img: 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAHAAACH5BAUAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=='
```

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for the `msg` argument, which will ignore `img` and `msgText` by the way.

```
loading :
{
    msg : $('PUT YOUR HTML HERE') // Accepts a jQuery object
}
```

Source: jquery.infinitescroll.js. Inside of `function infscr_create`:

```
// Define loading.msg
opts.loading.msg = opts.loading.msg || $('<div id="infscr-loading"><img alt="Loading..." src="' + opts.loading.img + '" /><div>' + opts.loading.msgText + '</div></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a gif inside the plugin. Either delete `loadingImg   : "/img/loading.gif",` or replace with something blank same size.